# Updating the field of the nested object not re-rendering the views (UI) in React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am developing a Web application using React and Redux as the front-end JavaScript framework. I am having a bit of a problem with rendering view and updating the Redux state/store value.

I have an input field which update the Redux state value. This is the event handler for onChange of my text field.

```
_handleNameInput= (event) => {
     this.props.updateField({
             name: 'name',
             value: event.target.value,
     })
}
```

In the reducer I am updating the field of the state like this

```
case RESTAURANT_CATEGORY_UPDATE_FIELD: {
            let freshState = { ...state };
            _.set(freshState, action.payload.name, action.payload.value);
            return freshState;
        }
```

I am using Lodash to update the field of the state object.

This is my default state

```
let defaultState = {
     name: ''
}
```

When the user is entering the input, I display the live state value on the view like this.

```
<h1>Name is: {this.props.name}</h1>
```

The above scenario works totally fine. It is displaying the live changes while I am changing the value of the input as well. The problem began when I use the nested object in the state. I updated the defaultState to this.

```
let defaultState = {
     form: {
        name: '',
     }
}
```

Then in the callback, I update like this.

```
this.props.updateField({
      name: 'form.name',
      value: event.target.value,
})
```

It is updating the redux state/store values of the nested property of the object. The problem is that when I display the live changes like this

```
<h1>{this.props.form.name}</h1>
```

It is not updating/rendering the view. How can I fix it?

Comment: What is your reducer looks like after updating it into the nested object?

Comment: I guess you are passing form.name as string so to access the new updated props you have to do like this.props['form.name']

Comment: Tried it. Not working

Comment: The state value is updated behind the scene. It is just not updating the UI.

Comment: Your state need to be immutable, when updating nested structures you need to make sure all references above are changed. Have a look at immer https://github.com/mweststrate/immer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you connect your component to redux via the `connect` function your component behaves as a `PureComponent`. That is, it will perform a shallow check of the new props, comparing them to previous props, to see if the component should perform an update.

In the first instance `name` is a top-level prop and it's change is detected so the update is performed.

In the second instance `form` is the top-level prop which has not changed so the update is prevented.

As suggested in the comments, you can use `immer` to ensure that the `form` object is replaced with a new object with the updated `name` property.

```
import produce from "immer";

return produce(state, draft => {
  _.set(draft, action.payload.name, action.payload.value);
});
```

In the second case it would effectively do the following..

```
return {
  ...state,
  form: {
    ...state.form,
    name: action.payload.value
  }
};
```

I would suggest though, that you reconsider having an action and reducer which update arbitrarily deeply nested fields and instead use something more specific.

RESTAURANT_CATEGORY_UPDATE_FORM_FIELD

```
return {
  ...state,
  form: {
    ...state.form,
    [action.payload.name]: action.payload.value
  }
};
```

or

```
return produce(state, draft => {
  draft.form[action.payload.name] = action.payload.value;
});
```

Comment: Thank u thank u so much. Learned a lot from ur answer.

Comment: I used the immer solution. It is just perfect.

Answer (score 0):

just because I was browsing this The immer thing looks cool but u can also just set a property off and on at the shallow end of your state

```
state.something.somethingelse = {
          ...state.something.somethingelse,
          updatedItem: posts,
          forceReRender: !state.something.somethingelse.forceReRender
        };
```

or

```
state.forceRender = !state.forceRender
```